# How do I set my default Music folder?

Tags: nautilus, symbolic-link

I recently moved all my music to a separate partion, moved `~/Music` to `~/Music-bak` and symlinked a new Music directory to the partition.

Nautilus updated the bookmarks to show "Music-Bak" under Computer. How do I tell it that "Music" is my real music folder?

Comment: The answers are the same, but I don't think I would have recognized the problem that I was struggling with in the post that has been flagged as a duplicate.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you mentioned, when you modify (rename / move) Music folder it will point to the new folder.
To force it to point to a different folder, modify file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` (it's a text file) and set the **XDG_MUSIC_DIR** parameter to point to your Music.

One can restart GNOME by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> together and
entering `restart` as the command, committed by the <kbd>⏎</kbd> key.

Comment: Listen to music while waiting :-)

Comment: This worked, but I needed to logout and log back in for the change to be visible in Nautilus

Answer (score 7):

Or use ubuntu tweak

[image: ubuntu tweak]

You download it from here : http://ubuntu-tweak.com/